# A reference to the object element Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I try to get to "content" from message entity.
This is my dump($messages):
http://s13.postimg.org/96ytd93vb/message.png

and my code in controller:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $messages = $em->getRepository('DashboardMainBundle:Message')->findBy(
        array(
            'receiver'=> $UserId,
            'id' => $Id
        ),
        array('createdAt' => 'ASC')
    );
```

How can I take "content" from this array in controller?

It looks simple but I tried many methods but each failed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you've currently shown, you got an array result. Currently your Message instance is being stored in `$messages[0]`. So you either have to iterate over your result (if you expect more than one record) or replace your `findBy` with `findOneBy` if you expect one record.

Comment: I don't know why but in this particular case foreach does not work / no display antyhing

Comment: What happens if you dump `$messages[0]`? Are you able to access `Message` instance then? If yes, then iterating over this result set should be just fine.

Comment: This is my dump($messages[0]): http://s21.postimg.org/f6e7b1rc7/message2.png     What now should I do?

Comment: Normally, you should be able to see your content by accessing `$messages[0]->getContent();` But this is not right if you expect to get more than one result. Try something else. Lets say you iterate like this - `foreach($messages as $item) {}` Try dumping `$item` between the curly braces and see what you get.

Comment: So if I try to ->getContent() i get error "Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object", if I try iterate and dump it's the same error :/

Comment: You're accessing content, yet it throws an error about id. Could you include your Message entity structure?

Comment: Actually, if you're having auto incrementing Id, why are you looking for this record with `findBy` ? You can easily replace with `findOneBy` which would return a single result(if found) or even better, you can just use `$em->getRepository('DashboardMainBundle:Message')->find($Id);` and get that row properly.